# IOS: NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow

Tags: ios, nsdate

how would I use NSDate's dateTimeIntervalSinceNow method to calculate the difference between today and an NSDate sometime in the future?

The examples I have seen all take arguments such as the number of seconds:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
```

I would like to perform the operation on another NSDate as in:

```
pseudocode

NSDate *date = NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSDate*)futureDate];
```

Can anyone suggest best way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want `[futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow]`?

Comment: What you are asking for makes absolutely no sense. What do you propose the result would be?

Comment: Dan, That did the job.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Dan in his comment, `[futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is garbled and unclear.

It sounds like you're trying to calculate the time interval between 2 dates. There's a method for that: `timeIntervalSinceDate:'

If you have a future date in a variable `futureDate`, your code might look like this (In Objective-C, since your pseudo-code looks sort of like Objective-C.)

```
NSTimeInterval difference = [futureDate timeIntervalSinceDate: NSDate.date]
```